# Upload an image to Strapi using Xamarin.Forms

Tags: api, xamarin, strapi

Currently im working on a xamarin forms app, that upload image to Strapi API. To take a picture from the camera i'm using CrossMedia Plugin

```
var photo = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new StoreCameraMediaOptions() { PhotoSize= PhotoSize.Small, CompressionQuality = 100 });

if (photo != null)
   ProductPic.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => { return photo.GetStream(); });
```

than send the photo in post Method :

```
 HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
 MultipartFormDataContent mt = new MultipartFormDataContent();
 photo.GetStream().Position = 0;
 StreamContent imagePart = new StreamContent(photo.GetStream());
 imagePart.Headers.Add("files", "jpg");
 mt.Add(imagePart, string.Format("image"), string.Format("bsk.jpeg"));

 var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("http://111.111.111.111:2222/upload", mt);
```

The problem that im facing this error

`"{\"statusCode\":400,\"error\":\"Bad Request\",\"message\":\"Bad Request\",\"data\":{\"errors\":[{\"id\":\"Upload.status.empty\",\"message\":\"Files are empty\"}]}}`

Answer (score 0):

The error points the image part is empty , try to replace `StreamContent` with `ByteArrayContent` , send `ByteArray` instead of `Stream` .

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
MultipartFormDataContent mt = new MultipartFormDataContent();
mt.Headers.ContentType.MediaType = "multipart/form-data";
var upfilebytes = File.ReadAllBytes(photo.Path);
mt.Add(new ByteArrayContent(upfilebytes, 0, upfilebytes.Count()), string.Format("image"), string.Format("bsk.jpeg"));

var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("http://111.111.111.111:2222/upload", mt);
```

Refer to

https://stackoverflow.com/a/61095848/8187800.