# How to retrieve the value from Headers in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-2.0

I have a variable fileContent which holds the value of FileName. I want the filename value to be stored in separate variable. How can I do this using C#?

[image]

Please find below code: This is what I have tried :

```
var fileContent = provider.Contents.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Headers.ContentDisposition.Name.Replace("\"", "") == "file");

var fileName = fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.FirstOrDefault();
```

I am getting the integer value as 34 in the variable fileName - instead of "Test.txt".. Please help to fix this!

Comment: Why C#2 tag if you use LINQ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get Content-Disposition parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30193569/get-content-disposition-parameters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't treat Filename as an array and leave out the .FirstOrDefault(). The 34 is probably the ascii value of the opening quote in the file name.

Personally I never use `var`. Replace with the actual type you need, and you will see a better error message.

To remove the quotes, you might try to call something like Trim('"'). I don't have C# here to test though :-(